# Unable to apply impulse twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create objects and apply an impulse on them
There is no problem with the first time, but it looks I have to wait until the last one is removed in order to apply an impulse to the new object. It is created but the impulse is not applied

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  CGPoint touchlocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
  MySpriteNode *object = [MySpriteNode node];
  object.position = touchlocation;
  [self addChild:object];
  [object.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0, 9.0)];
  [self performSelector:@selector(removeObject:) withObject:object afterDelay:1.5];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem comes creating the physicsBody like this

```
[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:texture size:object.size];
```

The first time, the impulse is really strong, and the next ones really soft. So it looks it doesn't work if you compare with the first impulse.
I really hope it's a bug if the iOS 8 Beta